# Forces with metric and imperial values

Tags: forces, work

I have been calculating the work needed to empty a tank (calculus 2) and I have noticed that the gravitational constant is not used in some problems to find the actual force. These problems are dealing with imperial units, not metric. I came across something online that said that in the metric system, mass is separate from force. Therefore, you would have to multiply by 9.8. It also said that the weight in the imperial units is the force. I am confused why the weight is the actual force.

(I don't have a background in physics)

Comment: Well, there are multiple 'imperial' systems (kind of like mks vs cgs 'metric' systems). The common 'imperial' one has the pound as a unit of force with the slug as a unit of mass, while another has the pound as a unit of mass and the poundal as a unit of force. The distinction between mass and force still exists, you just have to know which system you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I came across something online that said that in the metric system, mass is separate from force. Therefore, you would have to multiply by 9.8.

That is almost right, but the issue is actually slightly different. The real issue is that “Imperial Units” are just plain messy. There are multiple different unit systems in the overall category of Imperial Units, and, more importantly for this question, there are multiple imperial units of mass.

The most common unit of mass is the “pound mass” which is often just called a “pound”. There is also a unit of force called the “pound force” which is often just called a “pound”. So when something refers simply to a “pound” then you have to infer from context if the quantity is a mass or a force. The legal definition of a pound is a mass, but actual usage is not so consistent.

Now, the pound force is related to the pound mass by $1 \ \mathrm{lb_{force}}=g \ 1 \mathrm{lb_{mass}}$ where $g\approx 32 \ \mathrm{ft/s^2}$. So there is a factor of $g$ inside a pound mass already. However, in keeping with the messiness of imperial units there is another mass unit called the slug which is related to the pound force by $1 \ \mathrm{lb_{force}}= 1\ \mathrm{ft/s^2} \ 1 \ \mathrm{slug}$. There is no factor of $g$ in the definition of the slug.

So if you are measuring forces in pounds and masses in slugs then you will see $g$ in all of the same places that you see $g$ using SI units. But if you are measuring forces in pounds (force) and masses in pounds (mass) then the factors of $g$ are absorbed into the units.

Answer (score 1):

In imperial units, everyone describes weight in pounds.  This leads to the kind of confusion that you are describing.  Weight is actually the normal force reaction due to the pull of gravity on an object that is at rest on a flat horizontal surface (e.g., a scale).  Since weight is NOT mass, it would be somewhat helpful if weight in the imperial system was more correctly given the name "pounds-force" while  mass in the imperial system was more correctly given the name "pounds-mass".

Based on my understanding of the issue, earth's surface gravity pulls on a 1 pound-mass with a force of 1 pound-force.  This 1 pound-force accelerates the mass at $32 ft/s^2$.  When doing conversions involving pounds-mass and pounds-force, that factor of 32 often shows up in the calculations.  This need to include a factor is not seen in the metric system, where 1 Newton has been defined as the force needed to accelerate a 1 kg mass at a rate of $1 m/s^2$.  It is for this reason that even though I live in the U.S., I prefer to do scientific calculations in the metric system, and in my opinion, it is a real shame that the U.S. didn't convert to the metric system decades ago.